# Индусский not in в C# при парсинге строк

Tags: c#, строки, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте! Не так давно начал программировать и изучать c#, встала необходимость использовать что-то вроде not in в коде, но подобных примеров в интернет не нашёл, поэтому спрошу здесь.

Требуется считать строку посимвольно, определив разделитель. Строка имеет следующий вид:

[символы до разделителя][разделитель, какой-то символ][символы после разделителя].

Символы до разделителя могут включать в себя 0...9, E, e, -, +

Помогите пожалуйста советом как это можно реализовать не прибегая к куче if-ов (единственное что пришло на ум)

```
string[] strs = inTextBox.Lines;
for (int j = 0; j < strs.Length - 1; j++){
if (strs[j] == "0") // 
... (куча других примеров разрешённых символов)
else
variable = strs[j];
break;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, вопрос. Пока что не вижу поводов не использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: Да, по поводу регулярных выражений - они подходят как раз для этого, но до них ещё не дошёл, поэтому хотелось и бы это реализовать по-простому "на пальцах".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вот это вам подойдет:

```
char variable = "ваша строка".First(x => !"0123456789eE+-".Contains(x));
```

Или вот вариант подлиннее, но прозще для восприятия:

```
const string symbols = "0123456789eE+-";
const string str = "ваша строка";
char variable;

foreach (var s in str)
{
    if (!symbols.Contains(s))
    {
        variable = s;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Большое и человеческое спасибо!
Первый вариант подошёл, но второй будет лучше, т.к. действительно проще понять что к чему.

Answer (score 1):

```
const string Delimiters = "0123456789Ee+-";

...
if(Delimiters.Contains(strs[j]))
{
    ...
}
```